# WooCommerce hook on shop page

Tags: woocommerce, themes, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm having problems with the shop main page of WooCommerce. I have all my products in two rows, that's OK. But after that, the products appear on a unordered list and I can't remove it by hooks and by CSS
I'll show you with an IMG
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB2Fu.png)

The items that are circled is what I don't want them to appear on the webpage

Comment: This might be your theme problem aka how did you looped in product archieve page. Or may be some other plugin.

It is too broad, until unless you come up with exact what code is working there.

Comment: If your current theme ask update , Please update your current theme & wocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the plugin/theme conflict. Do check the Woocommerce -> System Status and look for errors.

Make sure you are using the latest version of Wordpress and Woocommerce.

How to debug:

[wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-debug-issues-after-updates](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-debug-issues-after-updates)

Perhaps it would be easier to find what is causing the conflict. Try temporarily switching back to the WordPress Twenty Sixteen Theme, or Storefront, and disable all plugins except for WooCommerce. If that resolves the issue, then slowly re-enable plugin one by one until you find the one that’s causing the conflict